# After three async cordova call completion, I need to make fourth call. How to achieve this?

Tags: javascript, cordova, promise

I have three cordova.exec calls and its executing aysnc. My objective is to call fourth cordova call after completing all three calls. I can't nest calls to make it sync but i need to call fourth after three call completion (like promise/when in jquery).

Comment: When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Thanks, Is there anything available in pure javascript??

Answer (score 3):

You will need the [Cordova promise polyfil](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-promise-polyfill). And then write your code like everyone else does it:

```
//exec as promise
var execPromise = function(){
  return new Promise(
    function(resolve,reject){
      cordova.exec.apply(
        cordova,
        [
          resolve,
          reject
        ].concat(
          Array.prototype.slice.apply(arguments)
        )
      )
    }
  );
}

Promise.all(
  [
    execPromise(args),
    execPromise(args),
    execPromise(args)
  ]
)
.then(
  function(results){
    console.log("three are done, results are:",results);//array of results
    return execPromise(args);
  }
)
.then(
  function(result){
    console.log("all are done, result:",result);
  }
)
.catch(
  function(err){
    console.log("something went wrong, error is:",err);
  }
);
```